# VRP benchmark instances with charging stations

Tags: vehicle-routing, benchmark

Are there any benchmark instances for VRP with charging stations? I also have various delivery points with charging stations in the city(Multiple Vehicles). How can I compare my formulation?

Comment: You might check http://www.vrp-rep.org

Comment: Would you see this [article](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/trsc.2013.0490) which published in informs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[E-VRP-NL](http://vrp-rep.org/variants/item/e-vrp-nl.html) has been used in [The electric vehicle routing problem with capacitated
charging stations](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02386167/file/The_electric_vehicle_routing_problem_with_capacitated_charging_stations-HAL.pdf). Also authors in the paper mentioned by *A.Omidi* design two new sets of benchmark instances for the E-VRPTW problem. A set of 56 large instances, each with 100 customers and 21 recharging stations, and a set of 36 small instances with 5, 10, and 15 customers per instance. All instances are created based on the benchmark instances for the VRPTW proposed by Solomon (1987).

Comment: I think this dataset uses only a single-vehicle.

Comment: Even if I distribute the customer among other EVs, I am still not sure how I am going to compare my result (This is the first time I am using dataset previously I use to create my own examples so I am not aware how can I compare my solution? like time taken, objection function value, etc and also I am using IBM  drop solve cloud solver to solve my model)

Comment: You are right, they considered a single-vehicle problem but you can still compare your solution to the benchmark solutions if your model is working for multiple vehicles by simply assuming a single vehicle in the system. If there is no benchmark for your specific problem (in general researchers compare a modified version of their work with some existing benchmark results in the literature), you may generate a set of those problems with all the specifications that you consider for your model.

Comment: There is another http://www.vrp-rep.org/datasets/item/2018-0004.html, but the one you shared has the same name in the zip folder files and name used in paper result, but the one I found has different names used in the paper and zip folder which I can't understand.

Comment: I am testing the dataset you suggested but can't replicate the results, I have asked a question here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/montoya-et-al-2017-benchmark-results can you take a look at it.